# Error while generating json content using jersy

Tags: json, jersey

I'm working on jersy project when a lunch tomcat server i get this exception :

MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json

This is my code :

```
 @Path("/activities") 
public class ActivityResource {

  private ActivityRepository activityRepository = new ActivityRepositoryStub();


   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public List<Activity> getAllActivities(){

    return activityRepository.findAllActivities();


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **jersy-media-moxy** jar in your Lib folder or add it in your pom.xml that why you have this error message

if you want to return xml content make shur that you have @XmlRootElement on your entity because jersy use JAXB to map java object to xml

```
@XmlRootElment
public class Activity {



}
```